# Overheating laptop dual Ati GPU HD4200 and discrete HD5400

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, radeon

I've a laptop which until now I'm using free Radeon drivers.

Now I'm thinking to switch to the proprietary Ati drivers due its cooler temperature. But I'm not sure what to do. My laptop has two graphic cards:

a) Integrated GPU Ati Mobility HD4200 series
b) Discrete GPU Ati Mobility HD5400 series

So, for which GPU should I download the driver and install? Integrated or discrete?

Thank you so much!!

Comment: Hello, it isn't duplicate content because I know how to install ati drivers. My question is different, I want to know which driver I should install because my laptop has an integrated and discrete GPU. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Well the HD4200 is not supported with the proprietary Catalyst drivers (only Legacy drivers are available with no new X.org support). So you should try to disable the onboard graphics, and install the current Catalyst drivers for the HD5400.

Comment: I see... Only have two options... Or install Legacy drivers with the two gpu working or disable integrated and install the HD5400 drivers. Is that correct? Thank you!!

Comment: @user44849, you will have not any chance to make them both work, because integrated cards do not have Crossfire/SLI capabilities. And since you have laptop, you will not be able to use dual-card configuration. So use suggested solution.

Comment: Ok, and, how can I disable the integrated GPU? Thank you very much!!

Comment: Usually it can be set in the BIOS. If not then I think it uses the discrete chip anyway, so you can just install Catalyst. But to be on the safe side, can you post your **glxinfo** output?

Comment: Hello!! Here is the result for the glxinfo: http://ubuntuone.com/3LEHeqecrXtrWwgDfU9gqr   Now I use the Radeon driver with the HD5400 GPU disabled by vga_switcheroo. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: You should put it on e.g. pastebin, and post a link here

Comment: Okay, so you are running the integrated graphics. Look at the BIOS settings, maybe you can turn it off. But before that, enable your discrete GPU.

Comment: Well, I've rebooted the laptop and looked into the BIOS interface, no option to disable the GPU. :-(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9796/discussion-between-user44849-and-meskobalazs)